# How to extend color beyond the top edge in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, scrollview

I have placed a linear gradient area at the top of a scrollview as below:

```
struct ExperimentView: View {
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {

        
        ScrollView {
          VStack {
            LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                .blue.opacity(0.5),
                .clear
              ],
              startPoint: .top,
              endPoint: .bottom
            )
            .frame(height: 200)
            
            Text("Element")
            Text("Element")
            Text("Element")
            
          }
      }
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

The problem is, the scroll view can be pulled downward and reveal the background color above the top edge.

[image]

So is there a way to extend the blue color upward beyond the top edge, so when pulled downward, it still looks continuing upward?

I tried to add a solid color above the gradient header, and set and offset to the VStack inside the scrollview:

```
struct ExperimentView: View {
  
  let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      
      
      ScrollView {
        VStack(spacing:0) {
          
          Color.blue.opacity(0.5)
            .frame(height: height)
          
          LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              .blue.opacity(0.5),
              .clear
            ],
            startPoint: .top,
            endPoint: .bottom
          )
          .frame(height: 200)
          
          Text("Element")
          Text("Element")
          Text("Element")
          
        }
        .offset(y: -height)
      }
      .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
    }
  }
}
```

While it seems to work with pulling down, the offset would leave a space with the height of the screen at the bottom of the scrollable area, leaving a full blank page when scrolling up, rather than bouncing back when reaching the last element inside the scrollview.

So is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could move the gradient to the background of the `ScrollView` instead:

```swift
NavigationStack {
    ScrollView {
        VStack {
            Text("Element")
            Text("Element")
            Text("Element")
        }
    }
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .background(alignment: .top) {
        LinearGradient(
            colors: [
                .blue.opacity(0.5),
                .clear
            ],
            startPoint: .top,
            endPoint: .bottom
        )
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .frame(height: 200)
    }
}
```

*EDIT* As you point out in your comment, this makes the gradient fixed. If you want it to move with the `VStack` then I would suggest moving it to the background of the `VStack` instead. Also:

- give the gradient more height and then apply an offset to move the extra height off-screen
- to prevent the "join" from being noticeable, I found it works best to use color stops that start off-screen with an opaque color
- apply top padding to either the `VStack` or to the first text element, to move the text down below the gradient (if required).

```
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        Text("Element")
        Text("Element")
        Text("Element")
    }
    .padding(.top, 200)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .background(alignment: .top) {
        LinearGradient(
            stops: [
                .init(color: .blue, location: 0),
                .init(color: .blue, location: 0.5),
                .init(color: .clear, location: 1),
            ],
            startPoint: .top,
            endPoint: .bottom
        )
        .frame(height: 800)
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        .offset(y: -600)
    }
}
.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
```

Alternatively, to build the `VStack` in the same way as before, the gradient could be moved to the background of a placeholder that is the first item in the `VStack`:

```swift
ScrollView {
    VStack {
        Color.clear
            .frame(height: 200)
            .background(alignment: .top) {
                // the LinearGradient, exactly as above
            }
        Text("Element")
        Text("Element")
        Text("Element")
    }
}
.ignoresSafeArea(.all)
```

Comment: This makes the gradient part fixed. I would still want it to be scrollable.

Comment: OK, answer updated with a scrolling version

Comment: Thanks, putting the color in .overlay works perfectly.

Comment: Pleased to hear it works. I didn't actually intend to put it in an overlay, so updated the answer to put it in the background instead. It doesn't make much differece if there is no overlap with actual content, but still I would suggest it is better to have it in the background.

Answer (score 1):

You can add some more blue color to the top of the `LinearGradient` by using `background`/`overlay` and offsetting the color by the height of the `LinearGradient`:

```
LinearGradient(
    colors: [
        .blue.opacity(0.5),
        .clear
    ],
    startPoint: .top,
    endPoint: .bottom
)
.frame(height: 200)
.background(alignment: .bottom) {
    Color.blue.opacity(0.5)
        .frame(height: 2000)
        .offset(y: -200)
}
```

Comment: Exactly, background/overlay is the right way to do this. Thanx.